# Hashmap Print Function Not Updating Sets

Tags: c++, hashmap, char

My hashmap print function appears to be faulty. It is printing the correct values, but the incorrect keys. In the code below, I get user input for two key/value pairs and it only prints out the key of the second input.

For example, for the first pair, I will input 12/"e", and the second pair, I will input 15/"f" and the output will be f | 12, f| 15. Does anybody know what is going on? I think it might be something with the char array, and I would use strings, but I can only use primitives for this task. The size of the char array for 100 is just an arbitrarily big number that I thought would not be exceeded by a user key. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _node
{
    char *key;
    int value;          /* For this, value will be of type int */
    struct _node *next; /* pointer to the next node in the list */
} node;

/* HashMap class */
class HashMap
{
private:
    node ** hashTable;
    int numSlots;
public:
    /* Initializes a hashmap given its set size */
    HashMap(int size)
    {
        numSlots = size;
        hashTable = new node*[size] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hashTable[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    /*** Hash function. ***/

    int hash(char *s)
    {
        int i;
        int sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; * (s + i) != '\0'; i++)
        {
            sum += *(s + i);
        }

        return (sum % numSlots);
    }

    /* Create a single node. */
    node *create_node(char *key, int value)
    {
        node *result = new node();
        result->key = key;
        result->value = value;
        result->next = NULL;

        return result;
    }

    /*
     *Stores given key/value pair in hashmap
     *returns boolean for success/failure
     */

    void set (char* key, int value)
    {
        int keyValue = hash(key);
        node *current = hashTable[keyValue];
        node *original = current;
        node *newNode;
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            hashTable[keyValue] = create_node(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            while (current != NULL)
            {
                current = current -> next;
            }

            if (current == NULL)
            {
                newNode = create_node(key, value);
                newNode -> next = original;
                hashTable[keyValue] = newNode;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Prints hash table */

    void print_hash_table()
    {
        int i;
        node *listIterator = NULL;

        for (i = 0 ; i < numSlots ; i++)
        {
            listIterator = hashTable[i];

            if (listIterator != NULL)
            {
                cout << listIterator->key << " | ";
                while (listIterator != NULL)
                {
                    cout << listIterator->value << " ";
                    listIterator = listIterator -> next;
                }
                cout << endl;
            }


        }

    }
};


int main()
{
    HashMap hash (128);
    char key[100];
    int value;

    cout << "Enter element to be inserted: ";
    cin >> value;
    cout << "Enter key at which element to be inserted: ";
    cin >> key;
    hash.set(key, value);
    cout << "Enter element to be inserted: ";
    cin >> value;
    cout << "Enter key at which element to be inserted: ";
    cin >> key;
    hash.set(key, value);
    hash.print_hash_table();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: This code is hard to debug....code shows strange behavior... check out http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/pPUDRe

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a character pointer to `set`, and storing that pointer in your map.  Then you change what's in `key`, which will *change the value of the first key that you've already stored*, and store the same pointer again in your map.  So both keys will have the same value.

This can also lead to pointers in the map pointing at invalid memory regions if they get deleted or the calling function returns, taking the passed in array out of scope.

You'll need to make a copy of your key when you store it in your hash map.